# Determining whether two special variants of knapsack have the same optimal value

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard, decision-problem, knapsack-problems

Given two unbounded knapsack instances, $K_1 = (W_1, weights, values), K_2 = (W_2, weights, values)$, where $W_1 \ne W_2$, what is the complexity of determining $v(K_1) = v(K_2)$ where $v$ returns the optimal sum of values given a knapsack instance?

I know that the decision problem of knapsack -- i.e. asking whether or not a knapsack instance can achieve a value of at least $k$ is NP-hard, but am having trouble reducing that to this particular decision problem. I conjecture that this remains NP-hard though.

Answer (score 0):

I have no proof, but I expect it's probably hard, because given a target value $t$, it is easy to construct a knapsack problem $K_2$ whose optimal value is $t$.  This means that your problem is at least as hard as testing, given $t$ and $K_1$ whether the optimal value of $K_1$ is equal to $t$.  I don't know whether that problem is NP-hard, but the related problem of testing whether the optimal value of $K_1$ is $\ge t$ is NP-hard.